# calling functions to main with parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters, call

taking a python class
not sure why it is saying (radius) parameter is "unresolved reference" in my [main.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6EGE.png)
this is the first time i have tried to run this code and there might be more errors through out but lets focus on this first one :P

utilities.py

```
import math

def calculate_circle_area(radius):
    """

    :param radius:
    :return:
    """
    area = math.pi * (radius ** 2)
    return area
```

main.py

```
import utilities


def main():
    float(input("enter the radius of a circle in cm:"))
    area = utilities.calculate_circle_area(radius)
    print("the area of the circle is:", area)
    float(input("enter radius of sphere in cm:"))
    volume = utilities.calculate_sphere_volume(radius)
    print("the volume of the sphere is:", volume)
    bmi = utilities.calculate_bmi()
    print("the body mass index is:", bmi)
    hypotenuse = utilities.calculate_hypotenuse()
    print("the hypotenuse length of the tight triangle is:", hypotenuse)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you mean: ‘radius = float(input("enter ...’?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate a variable before you can pass it. In your case, the `radius` variable. Even in the image that you shared, the error shows line 6.

```py
import utilities


def main():
    radius = float(input("enter the radius of a circle in cm:")) #This one's mandatory, otherwise you will get that reference error
    area = utilities.calculate_circle_area(radius)
    print("the area of the circle is:", area)
    radius = float(input("enter radius of sphere in cm:"))
    volume = utilities.calculate_sphere_volume(radius)
    print("the volume of the sphere is:", volume)
    bmi = utilities.calculate_bmi()
    print("the body mass index is:", bmi)
    hypotenuse = utilities.calculate_hypotenuse()
    print("the hypotenuse length of the tight triangle is:", hypotenuse)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```